# HTACCESS - Remove path from address

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess, I want to take `domain.com/path/file.php` and it go to `domain.com/file.php?var1=path`

I thought the below would work but, apparently not.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*?)\/(.*?)/?$ /$2.php?var1=$1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want `domain.com/path/file.php` or `domain.com/path/file` ?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Whatever the file is - whether it's best-song.mp3, going to ```domain.com/music/best-song.mp3``` should actually find the file in the root and append the path, ie, ```domain.com/best-song.mp3?var1=music```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.+)$ $2?var1=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you - this works perfectly. Can you explain the rewrite condition, please?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2` checks presence of file with value captured in second captured group which is `(.+)`